# Inquiry Regarding Statistical Analysis of Gene Expression Data Using R

Tags: expression, r-package

I am currently working on a research project involving the analysis of gene expression data.

In my study, I have collected gene expression data for 82 genes in both treated (with drugs) and untreated (control) groups. My primary objective is to compare the means and fold changes of these 82 genes between the two groups.

Considering your proficiency in statistical analysis, particularly with R, I am seeking advice on the most appropriate statistical methods and R packages to use for this specific analysis.

Best,
Khlood

I attempted to conduct a two-way ANOVA for the analysis, but for some reason, I encountered difficulties and was unable to complete it successfully.